# Как правильно реализовать тестовое задание на должность PHP developer?

Tags: php, инспекция-кода, задание-на-собеседовании

HR менеджер дал тестовое задание. Я выполнил. В ответ он сказал, что

> я получил только краткий фидбек - не понравилось качество и стиль реализации.

Хочу вашего совета, что я не так написал.
Вот задание:

```
Тестовое задание #1:

Версии ПО: PHP 5.3-5.6

Необходимо реализовать функцию, которая произведет чтение данных файла и вернет обработанные данные в указанном виде.

Функция должна:
 - Считать данные с файла
 - Разбить данные по строкам в массив
 - Отфильтровать массив таким образом, чтобы в нем остались лишь строки содержащие только числа
 - Суммировать числа в каждой строке
 - Отсортировать полученные суммы в порядке убывания
 - Вернуть результат

Пример кода:

     # Путь к файлу данных  $file = __DIR__ . '/datalist.txt'; 
     # Передаем данные в функцию и получаем результат  $result = getResult( $file ); 
     # Отображаем результат  echo '<pre>'; 
     var_export( $result );

      function getResult ( $file )  {
          # @TODO Реализовать...  }

     Пример результата работы функции:  array (    82 => 16396,    19 =>
     16169,    71 => 15864,    73 => 15224,    81 => 14244    ...
```

Кусок файла datalist.txt:

```
55 NTfy 591 405 kLj 48 644 768 164 ubd 837 oTft GPQV 163 ja 445 961
431 574 168
375 380 427 670 610 284 765 48 687 660 377 333 914 70 146 328 301 925 266
620 237 137 584 427 308 939 660 917 59 864
j hHo 279 tqpg 617 870 CoNJ 173 czgW 301 299 134 820 625 U 369 165 hutPN jiq 31 575 46 NS 397 378 954 764
```

Как я это реализовал:

```
<?php

# Путь к файлу данных
$file = __DIR__ . '/datalist.txt';
# Передаем данные в функцию и получаем результат
$result = getResult($file);
# Отображаем результат
echo '<pre>';
var_export($result);

function getResult($file) {
#Считать данные с файла.
#Разбить данные по строкам в массив
    $line = file($file);
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($line as $value) {
        $ArrayLine = explode(' ', $value);
        foreach ($ArrayLine as $Record) {
            $result[$i] = 0;
#Отфильтровать массив таким образом, чтобы в нем остались лишь строки содержащие только числа
            $CheckString = preg_replace('~[^A-Za-z]+~', '', $Record);
            if (strlen($CheckString) > 0) {
                unset($result[$i]);
                break;
            };
            $res = (int) $Record;
#Суммировать числа в каждой строке
            $result[$i] += $res;
        }
        $i++;
    }
#Отсортировать полученные суммы в порядке убывания
    arsort($result);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: «не понравилось качество и стиль реализации» — не волнуйтесь. «Забейте» на эту компанию, раз они такие развернутые комментарии дают. В черный список её и поделом с ней. ;)

Comment: Согласен с предыдущим оратором; в то же время проверку на непригодность строки можно делать до разбиения её на "слова" и суммирования с последующим `unset`. Ещё можно `strcspn` использовать, но это уже совсем придирки.

Comment: Спасибо за коментарии и поддержку))) А может я неправильно понял задание, может нужно было реализовать с стиле ООП? Вроде написано "реализовать функцию".

Comment: @AlexanderBragin как бы то ни было - можете помочь и написать ответ, что где как можно улучшить и сделать проффессиональнее. Метку [tag:инспекция-кода] поставил. Вроде подходит под условия

Comment: @plavv постараюсь сейчас написать решение, как я это вижу с комментариями. И вот ведь люди, не пишут в ТЗ про то, какие числа могут быть в файле: целые/не целые, положительные/отрицательные...

Comment: Подозреваю, от вас хотели увидеть потоковую обработку файла, а не загрузку его целиком в оперативную память

Comment: @plavv в ответе написал, как я это виже + комментарии и дополнительная информация для вас.

Comment: @plavv и если можно ещё отправить к ним решения, если хотите пройти у них собеседование. И считаете, что код вас устраивает и в него добавлять ничего не нужно (можете и добавить/изменить) — смело отправляйте задание. Правильно прислали решение или нет — они вам ответять. А то, что вам «помогли» прийти к этому решению — это уже не их дело. Наоборот то, что делаете в шаги в его решении адекватная компания в "+" должна взять (ну если начнет спрашивать как вы к этому решению пришли). P.S.: Это как раз и называется работа в команде ;)

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую :)

Comment: @plavv если не примут — пишите, будем додумывать вместе :)

Comment: @plavv мы код немного переписали. [Lyth](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/256109/lyth) ошибку у меня нашёл. В комментариях под ответом прочтёте.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Код**

```php
<?php

/**
 * Функция производит чтение данных из файла и возвращает обработанные данные согласно алгоритму
 * - Считать данные с файла
 * - Разбить данные по строкам в массив
 * - Отфильтровать массив таким образом, чтобы в нем остались лишь строки содержащие только числа
 * - Суммировать числа в каждой строке
 * - Отсортировать полученные суммы в порядке убывания
 * - Вернуть результат
 *
 * @param string $file
 * @return array
 */
function getResult($file) {
    $numbers = [];

    $handle = @fopen($file, 'r');
    if ($handle) {
        // Читаем файл построчно
        while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
            // Удаляет пробелы (или другие символы) из начала и конца строки
            $buffer = trim($buffer);

            if (preg_match('/^[\d ]+$/', $buffer)) {
                // Разбиваем строку на числа, складываем получившийся массив чисел и записываем в массив
                $numbers[] = array_sum(explode(' ', $buffer));
            }
        }
    }

    // Сортируем массив по возрастанию (без сохранения отношений с ключами)
    rsort($numbers);

    return $numbers;
}

$result = getResult(__DIR__ . '/datalist.txt');

print_r($result);
```

**Комментарии к коду:**

- По входному файлу, в примере, делаю следующий вывод. Функция разработана с учетом того, что числа только положительные и целые, и внутри слов нету чисел, например, oT89ft. И число не может идти рядом со словом, например, 200NTfy (то есть будет ли он считаться числом после удаление «нечисел»).
- Хоть в алгоритме указан шаг *Разбить данные по строкам в массив*, он пропускается, чтобы не «забивать» память (не происходило переполнение памяти). Потом что строк в файле может быть очень много. Чтение происходит построчно и в массив сразу вычисляется и записывается сумма.
- Длина строки при чтении ограничена `length - 1 байт`
- Не стал «доходить по паранойи»: сортирую массив встроенной в PHP функцией и не стал делать какой-нибудь composer-пакет с тестами.
- Комментарии на русском... Желательно на англ. писать, если компании не против, где работать будете — потом пригодится :)

**Дополнительная информация**

При написании (форматировании кода) я стараюсь следовать [PHP Standards Recommendations](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/), в частности:

- [PSR-1: Basic Coding Standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/)
- [PSR-2: Coding Style Guide](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/)

Изучите информацию на сайте — пригодится.

И всегда обращайтесь и изучайте информацию по PHP на [официальном сайте](http://php.net/). [Документация](http://php.net/docs.php) на [русск.](http://php.net/manual/ru/) или [англ.](http://php.net/manual/en/) языках.

**И не бойтесь ошибаться! Задавать любые вопросы на Stack Overflow!**

Comment: Сейчас ещё некоторые нюансы внесу и добавлю некоторые ссылки дополнительные ссылки по оформлению PHP. Может пригодится. Проверю также работу в версии 5.3-5.6, а то у меня PHP 7 стоит, хоть и не стал особо ничего мудрить, но проверить нужно.

Comment: В задании сказано оставить "лишь строки содержащие только числа" - т.е. строку с любыми буквами надо пропускать целиком, а не пытаться выделить из неё числа.

Comment: @lyth точно! Вы правы. Переписал код. Спасибо, что заметили!

Comment: @lyth если по изложению и коду есть ещё какая-та критика (можно что-то улучшить), в хорошом смысле этого слова, напишите, пожалуйста — я сам постоянно учусь. Учту.

Answer (score 2):

Согласен с Alexander Bragin, задание слишком игрушечное для того чтоб стоило сильно задумываться о реализации. Кроме того в задачи фактически приведён готовый алгоритм, как должна работать функция, что несколько ограничивает свободу действий в реализации (не ясно можно ли было к примеру разбить функцию или не хранить в памяти фаил целиком а считывать его построчно ...).

Но могу сделать пару замечаний по стилю.

1. Имена переменных - почему некоторые переменные записаны в CamelCase, а другие с маленькой буквы.
2. Отступы в комментариях. Комментарии легче читаются когда они по отступам не выделяются от кода (либо идут в конце строки).
3. Возможный баг: в задаче сказано что нужно убрать все строки которые содержат не числа. Вы проверяете регуляркой только наличие латинских букв. Если в примере будут какие либо символы то функция будет работать некорректно (не проверял код).
4. Незакрыт тэг `<pre>`, хотя возможно это просто не весь код.

Comment: >Как правило в php используется нижнее подчеркивание для имен переменных и функций

эм... Вы серьезно?

Comment: @DaemonHK из-за наличия стандартной библиотеки с бешеной неконсистентностью каждый волен строить свои предположения

Comment: @DaemonHK Убрал про функции, ориентировался на стандартную библиотеку. В PSR-1 действительно прописано что должно быть в `camelCase`.

Answer (score 1):

Можно было бы более лаконично выполнить задание:

```
<?php

$file = __DIR__ .'/datalist.txt';
$result = getResult($file);

echo '<pre>'; var_export($result); echo '</pre>';


function getResult($file) {
    $result = array_map(
        function ($item) {
            return array_sum(explode(' ', $item));
        },
        array_filter(
            file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES|FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES),
            function ($item) {
                return preg_match('~^[\s\d]+$~', $item);
            }
        )
    );

    arsort($result);
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
# Путь к файлу данных
$file = __DIR__ . '/datalist.txt';

# Передаем данные в функцию и получаем результат
$result = getResult($file);

# Отображаем результат
echo '<pre>';
var_export($result);
echo "</pre>\n";

function getResult ($file)
{
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        if ($lines = file($file, FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES)) {
            foreach ($lines as $index => $line) {
                $line = trim($line);
                preg_match_all('/\d\d{0,}/', $line, $matches);
                if (!empty($matches[0]) && $line === implode(' ', $matches[0])) {
                    $lines[$index] = array_sum($matches[0]);
                } else {
                    unset($lines[$index]);
                }
            }

            if (empty($lines)) {
                return "Numbers don't found";
            } else {
                rsort($lines);
                return $lines;
            }
        } else {
            return 'File empty or has wrong structure';
        }
    } else {
        return 'File not found';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

// Путь к файлу данных
$file = __DIR__ . '/datalist.txt';

// Передаем данные в функцию и получаем результат
$result = getResult($file);

// Отображаем результат
printResult($result);

// functions
function getResult($fileName) {
    $content = file_get_contents($fileName);
    $rows = explode("\n", $content);

    $arrWithNums = array_filter($rows, 'getRowsThatContainNumber');

    $arrWithSum = array();
    foreach ($arrWithNums as $str) {
        $nums = explode(' ', $str);
        $arrWithSum[] = array_sum($nums);
    }

    arsort($arrWithSum);

    return $arrWithSum;
}

function getRowsThatContainNumber($row) {
    $rowWithoutSpaces = str_replace(' ', '', $row);
    if (ctype_digit($rowWithoutSpaces)) {
        return $row;
    }
}

function printResult($var) {
    echo '<pre>';
    var_export($var);
}
```